# clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Project/SDWebImage-3.7.1/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libSDWebImage.a'

Tags: xcode, facebook, xcode6, sdwebimage

I am trying to send my app for review to facebook. I am following this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review) but i am stuck at the section of

> Build the Simulator Package

I am setting this in console:

`xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.1`

And i am getting the next error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Project/SDWebImage-3.7.1/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libSDWebImage.a'
```

I have been searching an it seems like a problem of architecture, here it is how i have muy tarjet build settings:
[image]

Any idea why the command `xcodebuild` can't find the `libSDWebImage.a`?
By the way, i am using xCode 6.1.1 and my app runs perfect on iPhone devices or simulator.

Answer (score 0):

By any one facing this problem, the solution is in this 2 steps:
1) Add static [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947139/xcodebuild-failure-clangerror-no-such-file-or-directory) 
2) Add [i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919970/no-architectures-to-compile-for-archs-i386-valid-archs-arm64-armv7-armv7s)

Comment: Fernando, you might be onto something here, but this 1 liner is not descriptive and can be confusing for some.  You might get more up-votes if you write out a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem while building an app for Facebook review. In my case the problem was: `ld` was searching `subproject.a` files in `$PROJECT_DIR/build` directory while in fact they where in `$PROJECT_DIR/project_name/subproject_folder/build` folder. I don't know how to fix it properly (any suggestions appreciated) so just did a soft link with `ln`.

The fun thing is: I don't have i386 architecture in settings, but it builds for i386 anyway.